# What causes a voltage drop at the input of this TL082CP Op-Amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, distortion, virtual-ground

I am breadboarding a circuit using a TL082CP Op-Amp, and I am reading consistent values with the multimeter.
The Op-Amp stage is powered with a single 9V battery, like this:
[image]
The Op-Amp stage looks like this:

[image]

However, a thing is making me scratch my head: If there is no input signal, I would expect to read around 4,5V at the non-inverting input and at the output of the Op-Amp, but actually if I measure with the multimeter the voltage between the + pin and the GND, I read around 2,5V, while the output is consistently at 4,5V.

Why is that?

I measured the voltage across the R4 resistor and it was 0V, so there must be no current on that; I tried to use a 10K resistor instead of a 470K, and then on the + pin I read around 4,5, so it must be that some sort of current is flowing at the input of the op-amp, and a bigger resistor just causes a voltage drop with that current. Am I wrong?

Is that current coming from the power stage or is it coming from the Op-Amp?

I also tried to disconnect the Op-Amp to see if the C5 capacitor was leaking, but it seemed to work fine.
I am kind of inexperienced with Op-Amps, and maybe I am doing a very basic error in measuring or breadboarding, but what confuses me is that the output of the circuit seems to be correct.
I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Is your multimeter only 1 Megohm input impedance? I would expect to see at least 4V after R4 with a 10Megohm DMM.

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me @brian.

Comment: @Andyaka except I've never heard of a 1M meter. Maybe the OP needs to link to the datasheet for whatever he has.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you for your answer. I don't know about the imput impedance, but it is a very cheap multimeter for sure. The thing that doesn't make any sense is that there is no voltage drop on R4, and the output of the op-amp seems correct. How does the multimeter's impedance affect that?

Comment: "there is no voltage drop on R4" ... when you aren't measuring IN+ io GND... What would 1Meg from IN+ to GND do to the voltages in that area?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I don't think I fully understand it, but I'm mostly self taught in this field. So basically everything is working fine except my multimeter is giving me an apparently "incorrect" read due to its probably low imput impedance? I would be cool with that.

Comment: That's my guess. I was hoping the spec for the DMM could confirm it. Or, can you beg/steal/borrow (or even buy) a second one (always useful) and measure Vout with it and Vin+ with this one, at the same time?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I think I found these informations about the multimeter I'm using: Input impedance is 1Mohm on DC also in mV ;
Input impedance is 0.5Mohm on AC. Does this confirm your guess? Does that mean that the DMM acts like a voltage divider?

Answer (score 1):

Is your multimeter only 1 Megohm input impedance? I would expect to see at least 4V after R4 with a 10Megohm DMM.

As it is, you have a potential divider between 4.5V and VIN+, formed by R4 and the DMM itself.

When you move the DMM to make any other measurement, the potential divider goes away.

I think this is enough to explain all your observations.

Comment: Thank you very much; very helpful.